How do I create a notification that shows up when a user leaves a tab or page?
I am looking to create a function that would remind users to stay on a webpage. As such, when they click another browser tab (or even better, when they leave the browser), I want to be able to inform them not to leave.
Does anyone happen to have any ideas? I am using Vue, JS, Shadcn for this webpage! Million thanks!
I suppose a simple way to do so is alert() but I noticed it only works within the page they are leaving, and that they would only see the notification after they return to the page which is counterintuitive. It is important to alert them when they are about to leave the webpage.

This question is opinion based. Its prohibited by stack overflow

Basically, no, at least not that I know. You can’t directly remind users to stay on a webpage as browsers have limitations to prevent intrusive actions. However, you can use the visibilitychange event to detect when someone switches tabs and show a gentle reminder to stay, which is not what you are actually asking for.
You could also use a confirmation dialog if users try to navigate away via links or the back button, but this won't capture tab switching.
